# RS485 MODBUS ARDUINO: Print multiple response data frame from soil sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, rs485, modbus, soil-sensing

**Hi everyone. I'm guiding myself from tutorial** https://how2electronics.com/measure-soil-nutrient-using-arduino-soil-npk-sensor/
I'm using...
**Hardware components:**
RS485
Arduino uno
Charger 9V (Only for soil sensor)
Soil moustiure (read 7 values)

**Hand tools and fabrication machines:**
Arduino IDE
**The manual is incomplete**
https://forum.arduino.cc/uploads/short-url/vRWYhwqOArAuTNiYGpBubyAUuA8.pdf
**The vendor provide me inquiry code: 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x04 0x08 and the response**
are for: hum, temp, ec, ph, n, p, k
**The scheme circuit are like these but without LCD and instead arduino nano i'm using Arduino uno:**
https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/5/7/c/57c7bd7f433232bce12540d56187b807d361c4fe.jpeg

The result values are incorrect. **The real temperature here is above 21 degrees and the humidity above aprox. 60 %.**
https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/f/d/c/fdce03537b2923b9cbfcb81080a2ffe3cb402c8f.png
This is the code:

```
//Library to convert Digital Output pins of the board to transmitter as well as receiver
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define RE 8
#define DE 7
const byte requestframe[] = {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x04, 0x08};
byte values[19];
SoftwareSerial mod(2, 3); // RX, TX ( Creates a new SoftwareSerial object )

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800);
  mod.begin(4800);
  pinMode(RE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DE, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    SoilParams();
    // We show the seven records.
    delay(2000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      switch (i) {
        case 1:
          Serial.print("| hum: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i) / 100.00);
          Serial.print(" % ");
          break;
        case 2:
          Serial.print(" temp: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i) / 100.00);
          Serial.print(" º ");
          break;
        case 3:
          Serial.print(" ec: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i));
          Serial.print("  ");
          break;
        case 4:
          Serial.print(" ph: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i));
          Serial.print(" ");
          break;
        case 5:
          Serial.print(" n: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i));
          Serial.print("  ");
          break;
        case 6:
          Serial.print(" p: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i));
          Serial.print("  ");
          break;
        case 7:
          Serial.print(" k: ");
          Serial.print(getInverseInt(values, i));
          Serial.print(" ");
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    Serial.println(" ");
  delay(1000);
}

void SoilParams() {
  digitalWrite(DE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RE, HIGH);
  if (mod.write(requestframe, sizeof(requestframe)) == 8) {
    mod.flush();
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(DE, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RE, LOW);
    while (!mod.available());
    for (byte i = 0; i < 19; i++){
        values[i] = mod.read();
        Serial.print(values[i], HEX);
        Serial.print(' ');
        delay(10);
    }
  }
}
// This function takes the buffer answered with the modbus frame, and gets the
// data that is in position pos.
int getInverseInt(byte *bufer, int pos) {
  int a = pos * 2 + 3; // We avoid the id, function and number of data.
  // We mount the word and return it as an int.
  return (int)((word)bufer[a] << 8 | (word)bufer[a + 1]);
}
```

Please , Anyone guide me to achieve for show the rigth data?

I'll be very greatful.

Comment: please, no pictures of text ... delete the picture and add the content of serial monitor as text ... format as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function getInverseInt is using the typecast of (word) which is unsigned, when it should use (short) which is signed, as in:

```c
return (int)((short)(bufer[a] << 8) | (short)bufer[a + 1]);
```